# C# application deployment issue with .mdf database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sql-server-express

I am working on a C# database application for learning and I'm trying to deploy it on client machine and getting connection problem.

```
//NOTE: path and database variables have correct info because it works on my dev machine
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + path + "\\" + databaseName + ";Integrated Security=True"
```

I am using **Install Shield** for creating setup and tried **Advance Installer** also.

On the other test machine I have installed:

- .Net Framework 4.5.2
- SQLLocalDB.msi (x64 bit)

Lastly, I installed my deployed setup file and I was getting an Exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904). A network related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server. 
The server was not found or not accessible.
Localdatabase Runtime error occured.
```

I also tried these in Connection String: (found in similar question on stackoverflow)

- `localhost`
- `localhost\\SQLExpress`
- `.\\SQLExpress`

But none of this work for me.

**NOTE:**

- My `LocalDB` connection string is working on dev machine.
- Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

**PS:** What I am trying to learn is a way to create an installer which installs some per-requeisites like .Net Framework, LocalDB etc and can run database based application on client machines without installing SQL Server separately. I am not sure if the `.mdf` way is the good fit for this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use SQLite Database because the process and function are almost similar. And the deployment is super easy; it just requires few DLLs to make it work.

**Guideline:**

First you will need `System.Data.SQLite` library and then needs to add `System.Data.SQLite.dll` as a reference in your project. Keep in mind that `SQLite.Interop.dll` also needs to be in your executables directory but doesn’t need to be added as a reference in your project.

Moreover, if your application is targeting Any CPU it is likely that you will get an exception. So make sure to navigate to **Project properties -> Build** and set the Platform target to the bit version of the `System.Data.SQLite.dll` binary you have downloaded.

As you are beginner so here is the step by step guideline along with sample code.

**Steps:**

1. **Navigate** to: `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`
2. **Search** For: `SQLite`
3. **Select** `System.Data.SQLite` (would be first result)
4. **Click** on Install
5. **Import** library

   ```
   using System.Data.SQLite;
   ```

The connection is ready and here is the **Sample Code**:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("sqlite.db3");

using(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=sqlite.db3")){
    using(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn)){
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                            [persons](
                            [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                            [name] VARCHAR(50) NULL
                            )";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [persons] (name) values('Atlas')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [persons]";

        using(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
            while(reader.Read()){
                MessageBox.Show(reader["name"].ToString());
            }

        conn.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

**Tips:**

- always use `try/catch` block for database operations
- If you don't prefer to use NuGet Package Manager then you can [download library from here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks @Atlas_Gondal, I will try this method and update back.

Comment: Thank you so much for step by step guide. I was able to deploy my first database application.

Answer (score 0):

Does one of these help?

[Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/)

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

[Attach a database file, located in the data directory, on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/attach-a-database-file-located-in-the-data-directory-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/)

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Comment: As mentioned in question, I have tried these method but no luck :(

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is without seeing more information then. I would wonder whether SQLExpress was installed properly.  Does it show up under Windows Services?  Also I would probably advise something like SQLite which would need no install and would be easy to package with a C# project BUT it might not fit all your needs - just something to look into.

Comment: what more information do you need??? `SQL Server VSS Writer` service is installed and the current status is `started`.